# Слово «содержание» появляется в оглавлении дважды

Tags: latex

Я пишу отчет. И слово «Содержание» появляется дважды в оглавлении, как вы можете видеть на прилагаемом изображении. Включает:

```
\usepackage{graphicx,color}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
 \usepackage{geometry}
 \usepackage{lastpage}
 \usepackage[figure]{totalcount}
 \usepackage{subfig}
 \usepackage[numbib]{tocbibind}
 \usepackage{cite}
 \usepackage{titlesec}
 \usepackage{enumitem}
 \usepackage{totcount}
```

Код:

```
\begin{document}
 ...
 \clearpage
 \tableofcontents
 \newpage
 \end{document}
 And what is compiled is:
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: тут вообще-то по-русски вопросы задают. исправьте, пожалуйста, вопрос, нажав [edit]. ну и минимальный пример для воспроизведения, конечно, нужен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё логично.

У вас есть *раздел* «Содержание». Который, как и любой другой раздел, тоже попадает в содержание, вместе с разделами «Введение», «Предлагаемое решение» и «Изучение производительности».

Первое «Содержание» — это *название раздела*, второе — часть текста раздела.

---

Если вы хотите удалить ссылку содержания на себя, метод зависит от вашего `\documentclass`. Загляните в документацию. Обычно раздел «Содержание» объявляется при помощи `\section*`, и таким образом не попадает в содержимое «Содержания». Возможно, у вас поддерживается команда `\tableofcontents*` вместо `\tableofcontents`, или `\PassOptionsToPackage{nottoc}{tocbibind}` до `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Comment: @And: Пожалуйста!